# A problem installing Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google

I downloaded Chrome, opened with Ubuntu software, but when I press install - nothing happens. In the bottom I get a message - `this software comes from a 3-rd party and may contain non-free components`. What do I do to install? Is it something in system settings?

Comment: Is your system a 32bit or 64bit version? Cause as I know Google chrome don't support 32 bit version anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I installed successfully using another installer (`gdebi`).

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Please also consider hitting the Accept button for your answer to mark your question as resolved.  It's the check-mark to the left of your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are dependencies that don't install for some reason.  Open a terminal and go to the folder where the .deb file is.

Type `sudo dpkg -i ./google*` and it should install it.

If you get an error about dependencies, type `sudo apt-get install -f` and it will install all the dependencies and then Chrome.

Comment: i'm trying it but i get a massage: "dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege". also after i type in the forced installation...

Comment: @T.raanan Apologies, I forgot you have to type `sudo` before `dpkg`, I edited my answer.